# Excel VBA - transpose, copy and paste into different rows, with conditions

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-statements

I am totally new to VBA in excel.

My data consists of Column G, with list of medals, and Column H, representing nations. I want to transpose my NOCs so that the J column represents Gold, and the rest being other medals(order doesn't matter whether it is silver or bronze as long as they are in the same row). Please refer to my image below, it would be self-explanatory on what I want to do.

I tried to code VBA so that it would copy three-down the column and transpose, but there are numerous times when it doesn't go by three. Sometimes there are two bronze medal, and sometimes no bronze medal.

How I thought it could work is to read column G and go down the column and look for Gold, and if "Gold" is found, then I want it to transpose the value of next column H, until the next Gold is found in column G.

Attached image below directed by red arrows is what I want to do.

I would highly appreciate your help.

[what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8rao.jpg)

==
I managed to solve my problem with help from stackoverflow, and this is the result.

```
Public Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRING
    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                  & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Current\Workbook.xlsm;"
    ' SQL STATEMENT
    strSQL = "TRANSFORM MAX(m.NOC) AS CountryCode" _
        & " SELECT m.[Event], m.[Event Gender]" _
        & " FROM (SELECT t.[Event], t.[Event Gender], t.[Medal], t.NOC," _
        & "              (SELECT Count(*) FROM [MAIN$] sub" _
        & "               WHERE sub.[Event] = t.[Event]" _
        & "                 AND sub.[Event Gender] = t.[Event Gender]" _
        & "                 AND sub.[Medal] = t.[Medal]" _
        & "                 AND (IIF(sub.[Medal]='Gold', 1, IIF(sub.[Medal]='Silver', 2, 3)) <" _
        & "                      IIF(t.[Medal]='Gold', 1, IIF(t.[Medal]='Silver', 2, 3))" _
        & "                      OR sub.[NOC] <= t.[NOC])) AS rn" _
        & "       FROM [MAIN$] t) m" _
        & " GROUP BY m.[Event], m.[Event Gender]" _
        & " PIVOT m.[Medal] & m.[rn] IN" _
        & "       ('Gold1', 'Gold2', 'Gold3', 'Silver1', 'Silver2', 'Silver3'," _
        & "        'Bronze1', 'Bronze2', 'Bronze3')"

    ' OPEN DB CONN
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i        

    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: conn.Close    
End Sub
```

Comment: The indicator column (i.e., event?) that you diagram with brackets is very important. What is in Column F or prior ones that define those 2 or 3 groupings?

Comment: it is the event of each game. So my column goes, A: year of olympics, B: Host City C: Sports(eg. Auqatics) D: Discipline(eg. Swimming) E: Event (eg. 100m backstroke) F: Event gender.

so what I am trying to get is a list of which nation won gold silver bronze for every event, in rows. :)

Comment: Are you using Excel for Windows or Mac?

Comment: Dear Parfait, I am using Excel 2013 for windows!

Comment: Dear Parfait this is the list of the full columns.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFC3I.jpg)  As you can see, some events have two bronze medals, totalling it up to 4 medals for an event. Although it is not shown in this list, there are some events where there are only one medal or two (gold, gold and silver). I would appreciate your help! thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

In stead of transposing it, you can do it algorithmically:

```
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox LastRow

'http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

dim start as long
dim finish as long

for medal = 2 to lastrow
   if thisworkbook.worksheets("worksheetname").cells(medal,7).value = "gold" then
    start = medal
         for next_medal = medal+1 to lastrow
            if thisworkbook.worksheets("worksheetname").cells(next_medal,7).value = "gold"
                finish = next_medal -1 'because it should not copy the next gold in the previous row of J
                medal = next_medal-1'because it starts looking for the next gold the next round at -1

                'copy/assign the cells you want to transpose:
                for transposing = start to finish
                thisworkbook.worksheets("worksheetname").cells(2+counter,10+transposing-start).value = thisworkbook.worksheets("worksheetname").cells(transposing,7).value 'writing the rest of the medals to the right of the first gold medal
                next transposing
                counter = counter + 1'ensuring the next row in J will be filled next time.
            end if
         next next_medal
     end if
next medal
```

My vba was compiling so I wrote it without verification, I hope you comprehend the idea :)

Comment: Thank you Maximilian brutus, I tried your code, and I changed cells in copy/assign the cells section (transposing,7) to (transposing,8) since I want to print the medals not the gold, silver, bronze per se. But when I run the codes, the results show rather a step by step of transposing, while I wanted was a compilation of 3-4 nations per row (gold-silver-bronze or gold-silver-bronze-bronze winning nations) and for every new set of event(in this case, it is reprented by medal 'gold'), I want it to be one row below.

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear, so this is what I meant! Thanks a bunch.  [link]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFC3I.jpg)

Comment: Excellent Heidi, what people usually do is they post their final working solution as an answer to their question, (or as edit in their initial question) so that in the future, people with the same problem, are helped by your struggle, improving` the world a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will definately do that. I am new to stackoverflow itself, so I wasn't wary about it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution specifically where your run the [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465B89C-2FF2-4CC8-BA60-2CD8484667E8). Excel for Windows can connect to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (.dll files) with ADO and query the current workbook.

Below assumes data resides in a tab named *Main* (change in query's `FROM` clause if needed) and results output in an empty tab named *Results*:

```
Public Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRING
    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Current\Workbook.xlsm;"
    ' SQL STATEMENT
    strSQL = "TRANSFORM MAX(m.NOC) AS CountryCode" _
            & " SELECT m.[Event], m.[Event Gender]" _
            & " FROM (SELECT t.[Event], t.[Event Gender], t.[Medal], t.NOC," _
            & "              (SELECT Count(*) FROM [MAIN$] sub" _
            & "               WHERE sub.[Event] = t.[Event]" _
            & "                 AND sub.[Event Gender] = t.[Event Gender]" _
            & "                 AND sub.[Medal] = t.[Medal]" _
            & "                 AND (IIF(sub.[Medal]='Gold', 1, IIF(sub.[Medal]='Silver', 2, 3)) <" _
            & "                      IIF(t.[Medal]='Gold', 1, IIF(t.[Medal]='Silver', 2, 3))" _
            & "                      OR sub.[NOC] <= t.[NOC])) AS rn" _
            & "       FROM [MAIN$] t) m" _
            & " GROUP BY m.[Event], m.[Event Gender]" _
            & " PIVOT m.[Medal] & m.[rn] IN" _
            & "       ('Gold1', 'Gold2', 'Gold3', 'Silver1', 'Silver2', 'Silver3'," _
            & "        'Bronze1', 'Bronze2', 'Bronze3')"

    ' OPEN DB CONN
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i        

    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: conn.Close    
End Sub
```

**Input**

[image: Data Input]

**Output**

[image: Data Output]

Comment: Dear Parfait, thank you so much! But one uqestion though. if an event has four medals total, for example one gold, one silver and two bronze, your code does not reflect the fourth medal (second bronze). It only counts to third medal. How could the fourth medal also be reflected?

Comment: and same goes for those with two silver medals.(eg: three medals total, but one gold, two silver). For me, the types of medal (gold, silver, bronze) does not matter at all, cause my data only emphasizes on the nationalities of  "medalists" regardless of their types. It's just that I need them to be in the same row. that's all. Thank you once again!

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with mor ethan three medals. Thank you so much Parfait! Your help really saved my time. Have a good day!

Comment: Solution is updated to account for multiple medals in any combination.

Comment: oh yay! Thank you!  As  Maximilian brutus III commented above, I will include it in my question so other people with same problem with me would take notice of it. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Heidi - your solution seems to be exactly my answer. Maximilian  even I believed you came up with a different solution from our proposed ones. And he meant answering your own question with it and not as edited extension to question. On StackOverflow to confirm resolution you click the tick mark on side of most helpful answer.